# Howto initialize constant QSet of QStrings

Tags: c++, qt

For a small test I want to init a QSet with some tokens stored as QString using C++. Is there a easy way to do something like this in C++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QSet>
#include <QString>

const QString TK_IDENT = "ID";
const QString TK_DESC  = "DESC";
const QString TK_SPEC  = "SPEC";

// THIS STUFF AS A ONELINER
const QSet<QString> TOKEN(TK_IDENT, TK_DESC, TK_SPEC);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 bool NOK = TOKEN.contains("TEST");
 bool OK  = TOKEN.contains("IDENT");
 std::cout << NOK << std::endl;
 std::cout << OK << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const QSet<QString> TOKEN{TK_IDENT, TK_DESC, TK_SPEC};` should work as of Qt 5.1

Answer (score 4):

When you look at QSet’s documentation you’ll find that it has a ctor that takes a `std::initializer_list`. So, using unified initialization syntax, write:

```
const QSet<QString> TOKEN{TK_IDENT, TK_DESC, TK_SPEC};
```

Since these are C++11 features, you’ll need a C++11 compiler. Also, Qt must be compiled accordingly. As far as I remember the initializer_list ctors were added back in Qt <strike>4.8</strike> 5.1. (Update: Igor’s comment was right: Some classes like `QStringList` gained their initlist ctor in 4.8, `QSet` got it in 5.1.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice std::initializer_list.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are unfortunate and don't have a C++11 capable environment, you can go through creating a list

```
const QSet<QString> TOKEN = QSet<QString>::fromList(QStringList() << TK_IDENT << TK_DESK << TK_SPEC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Also note that the tokens should be `QString` literals so as not to pessimize the code prematurely. A `QStringLiteral` is what it states on the box: a mechanism that uses the compiler to generate the internal data structure of a `QString` at compile-time, instead of having to go through a UTF8-to-UTF16 translation and string instantiation at runtime:

```
const auto TK_IDENT = QStringLiteral("ID");
const auto TK_DESC  = QStringLiteral("DESC");
const auto TK_SPEC  = QStringLiteral("SPEC");

const QSet<QString> TOKEN{TK_IDENT, TK_DESC, TK_SPEC};
```